# How to populate array with multiple data types inside?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to populate "markers" array that contains object and string. I have another javascript object stored in obj variable and I want to extract data from it and store it into markers array.
I am populating array with following code

```
  for (i = 0; i < obj.results.bindings.length; i++) { 
    markers[i].content = obj.results.bindings[i].placeName.value;
    markers[i].coords.lat = Number(obj.results.bindings[i].lat.value);
    markers[i].coords.lng = Number(obj.results.bindings[i].long.value);

  }
```

and markers array looks like this (populated manually, not by for loop)

```
var markers = [
    {
      coords:{lat:37.8707,lng:32.5050},
      content:'<h1>Mevlana museum</h1>'
    },
    {
      coords:{lat:37.8699,lng:32.4993},
      content:'<h1>Kapu Camii</h1>'
    },
    {
      coords:{lat:37.8749,lng:32.4931},
      content:'<h1>Karatay Madrasa</h1>'
    },
    {
      coords:{lat:37.8749,lng:32.4931},
      content:'<h1>Karatay Madrasa</h1>'
    },
    {
      coords:{lat:37.8749,lng:32.4931},
      content:'<h1>Karatay Madrasa</h1>'
    }
  ];
```

Now when javascript object 'obj' have same number of nested objects as elements of markers it works fine but when 'obj' have more nested objects than markers array has elements problems. I just want to add rest of the nested objects from 'obj' into markers. Why doesn't markers array grow dinamically when I add new elements in the for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

Array should not grow dynamically. You could use push/pop method.

```
markers = [];

for (i = 0; i < obj.results.bindings.length; i++) { 
    markers.push({
        content : obj.results.bindings[i].placeName.value,
        coords : {
          lat : Number(obj.results.bindings[i].lat.value),
          lng : Number(obj.results.bindings[i].long.value)
        }
    })

}
```

I try again with your code below:

```
for (i = 0; i < obj.results.bindings.length; i++) {
    markers[i] = {};
    markers[i].content = obj.results.bindings[i].placeName.value;
    markers[i].coords= {};
    markers[i].coords.lat = Number(obj.results.bindings[i].lat.value);
    markers[i].coords.lng = Number(obj.results.bindings[i].long.value);

}
```

I guess that you didn't assign the type as object, so it went wrong.

Please let me know if this works too.

Comment: Your statement is not true, array will grow dynamically. You can try with simple test like this `let arr = []; arr[2] = 'abc' console.log(arr)`

Comment: Sorry for poor English. That's not what I mean. I modify the statement to "should not". sorry for that.

Comment: As I know array grows dinamically in javascript but I couldn't figure out why my code wasn't working, anyway solution you wrote works for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `forEach` of your `obj.results.bindings` then construct each and every markers that you want and eventually push into the array as below

```js
let obj = {
 results: {
   bindings: [
          { placeName: 'cali',  lat: '123',  long: '456' },
          { placeName: 'hawaii',  lat: '555',  long: '333'},
          { placeName: 'korea',  lat: '777',  long: '888' }]
        }
};

let markers = [];
obj.results.bindings.forEach(item => {
 let mar = { content: '', coords: {}};
  mar.content = item.placeName;
  mar.coords.lat = Number(item.lat);
  mar.coords.lng = Number(item.long);
  
  markers.push(mar)
})

console.log(markers)
```